Cannot begin debug session for ESP32-S3-DevKitC-1 in PlatformIO
My setup is the following:

ESP32-S3-DevKitC-1 board
Ubuntu 23.10
Visual Studio Code v1.88.0
PlatformIO v3.3.3
ESP-IDF v1.7.1 (extension) v5.3 (framework)

I connected both USB ports to my computer (/dev/ttyACM0 is the USB/JTAG and /dev/ttyUSB0 is the UART). I created a sample project, built and uploaded.
This is my platfomio.ini file:
[env:esp32-s3-devkitc-1]
platform = espressif32
board = esp32-s3-devkitc-1
framework = espidf
build_type = debug  
build_flags =
        ${env.build_flags}
         -D EVE_CS=47
         -D EVE_PDN=11
         -D EVE_SCK=45
         -D EVE_MISO=35
         -D EVE_MOSI=21
         -D EVE_NHD_50

debug_tool = esp-builtin
debug_init_break = tbreak setup
debug_speed = 500

upload_protocol = esptool
upload_speed = 921600         ; <-- not sure if it's needed
upload_port = /dev/ttyACM0

monitor_speed = 115200
monitor_port = /dev/ttyUSB1

So my "blink" firmware is running.
Now I want to try to start a debug session. I read the docs here but when I click on Run > Start debugging, it just compiles again the code and nothing else happens.
Here my launch.json file:
// AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED FILE. PLEASE DO NOT MODIFY IT MANUALLY
//
// PlatformIO Debugging Solution
//
// Documentation: https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/plus/debugging.html
// Configuration: https://docs.platformio.org/en/latest/projectconf/sections/env/options/debug/index.html

{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "platformio-debug",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "PIO Debug",
            "executable": "/home/myproject/.pio/build/esp32-s3-devkitc-1/firmware.elf",
            "projectEnvName": "esp32-s3-devkitc-1",
            "toolchainBinDir": "/home/mark/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32s3/bin",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "preLaunchTask": {
                "type": "PlatformIO",
                "task": "Pre-Debug"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "platformio-debug",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "PIO Debug (skip Pre-Debug)",
            "executable": "/home/myproject/.pio/build/esp32-s3-devkitc-1/firmware.elf",
            "projectEnvName": "esp32-s3-devkitc-1",
            "toolchainBinDir": "/home/mark/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32s3/bin",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart"
        },
        {
            "type": "platformio-debug",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "PIO Debug (without uploading)",
            "executable": "/home/myproject/.pio/build/esp32-s3-devkitc-1/firmware.elf",
            "projectEnvName": "esp32-s3-devkitc-1",
            "toolchainBinDir": "/home/mark/.platformio/packages/toolchain-xtensa-esp32s3/bin",
            "internalConsoleOptions": "openOnSessionStart",
            "loadMode": "manual"
        }
    ]
}

What am I missing?
